# git : give me the repo, nuke everything local, I don't care

Tags: git

Does git have any pull/checkout 'nuclear option' to get the repo?
I don't care about any conflicts, I don't need any of my local stuff, 
just want the goods so I can work.

[edit]
to clarify my issues:

```
$ git pull
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:

<...files I couldn't care less about...>

Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:

<...more files I couldn't care less about...>
```

Comment: `git clean -xdf & git reset --hard & git pull`

Comment: what dose clean -xdf do?

Comment: @LoganBender `clean -xdf` removes all files and directories that are not version controlled by Git (and does not care if they are normally ignored by Git)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Better for you to understand the various git commands then to just find the one you need "right now" as you will come up with this situation many times and just learn piecemeal while grumbling and blaming git.

EDIT: I went ahead and tried all the options and this should do it. Thanks to pauljz in the comments.

```
git clean -df # remove untracked files AND directories
git reset HEAD --hard # revert any uncommitted changes
```

**The above should be all you need.**

Other options:

```
git pull -f # replace local files even if you have unpushed commits.
```

or

```
git reset HEAD --hard # remove unchanged, uncommitted files
git pull
```

or

```
git clean -f # remove untracked files (uncommitted files)
git pull
```

Comment: `git clean -f -d` is probably worth adding in as well, to clear out untracked files and directories.

Comment: clean -f cleared up the first error "error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:"  but not the untracked files error

Comment: @LoganBender do `git reset --hard` too, and then try `git pull` and if that does not work `git pull -f`

Comment: Logan, see pauljz's comment `git clean -f -d`, should be able to shortcut that to `git clean -fd`.

Comment: git clean -df# will only effect my current directory and sub dirs, correct?

Comment: It will only affect the entire local repo from the top level down.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the steps listed in the other answers don't work, because [rant redacted]. In that case, your "tactical nuke" option is to:

(If necessary) reset uncommitted local changes so you can switch:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Create and switch to a different local branch:

```
git checkout -b tempBranch
```

Force delete the (local copy of the) branch with the issues:

```
git branch -D targetBranch
```

Checkout and switch to a clean copy of the target branch from remote:

```
git checkout -b targetBranch origin/targetBranch
```

Clean up by deleting the temporary local branch you made:

```
git branch -D tempBranch
```

If that doesn't work, the "strategic nuke" option is to delete the repo and clone it again.

Answer (score 4):

You could always delete the entire folder of your existing repo, and then create a new one with `git clone`

Comment: This seems like the right idea to me: cd ..; rm -rf <repo> ; git clone <repo>

Comment: This can take a long time depending on the size of the repo / internet connection, is rather wasteful in general and is pretty much the "I give up" method. One should rather learn the commands to reset everything properly.  Then it gets easier the next time you need to do it.

Comment: This is what worked best for me.  I tried a myriad of other commands suggested here and in other threads, and this is the only thing that cleared up the "changes" git perceived, but didn't exist.